# Can you use Azure AD with SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, active-directory, azure

I will have SharePoint 2010 running in Azure (moving it from another environment).  I'd like to use Azure AD instead of having to stand up domain controllers within Azure.  I have seen articles on doing this with SharePoint 2013, but not SharePoint 2010.

In my case, SharePoint 2010 will run in Azure VMs.  I will use Azure AD Connect (DirSync) to keep our identities synced with the environment.  I believe this will allow the current SharePoint 2010 on-prem connection to seamlessly work after moving SharePoint to Azure, but want to check with others first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have Active Directory, thus Domain Controllers, for SharePoint. It's just part of the requirements. Since you mentioned DirSync (or the replacement, AAD Connect), this means you already have Active Directory in place.

What you can do is run SharePoint 2010 on Azure VMs but have a VPN/ExpressRoute connection back to your internal network where your DCs reside. This way your SharePoint/SQL Servers would be joined to Active Directory and you could just use standard AD accounts, no Azure AD complication required.

Comment: Note that according to this article you can use Azure AD directly with SharePoint 2013: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn635311.aspx.  What you recommend may be better with SharePoint 2010, though.

Comment: That's for end users, you still need on-prem Active Directory. Hence, there's little reason to go down that route.